# Can Ingress Controllers use Selector based rules?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have deployed a statefulset in AKS - My goal is to load balance traffic to my statefulset.

From my understanding I can define a LoadBalancer Service that can route traffic based on Selectors, something like this.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: web
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

However I don't want to necessarily go down the LoadBalance route and I would prefer Ingress doing this work for me,   My question is can any of the ingress controller support routing rules which can do Path based routing to  endpoints based on selectors? Instead of routing to another service.

**Update**
To elaborate more on the scenario - Each pod in my statefulset is a stateless node doing data processing of a HTTP feed. I want my ingress service to be able to load balance traffic across these statefulset pods ( honoring keep-alives etc), however given the nature of statefulsets in k8s they are currently exposed through a headless service. I am not sure if a headless service can load balance traffic to my statefulsets?

**Update 2**
Quick search reveals [headless](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) service does ***not***  loadbalance

`Sometimes you don't need load-balancing and a single Service IP. In this case, you can create what are termed "headless" Services, by explicitly specifying "None" for the cluster IP (.spec.clusterIP).`

Comment: `...can do Path based routing to endpoints based on selectors`. This statement basically is the Ingress itself. You have a service with selectors, and the Ingress Controller passes traffic to this service, which goes to the backends with that selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure if a headless service can load balance traffic to my statefulsets?

The first answer is "no". Why?

k8s Service is implemented by the kube-proxy. Kube-proxy itself can work in two modes:

1. iptables (also known as netfilter)
2. ipvs (also known as LVS/Linux Virtual Server)

load balancing in case of iptables mode is a NAT iptables rule: from ClusterIP address to the list of Endpoints

load balancing in case of ipvs mode is a VIP (LVS Virtual IP) with the Endpoints as upstreams

So, when you create k8s Service with clusterIP set to None you are exactly saying:

"I need this service **WITHOUT** load balancing"

Setting up the clusterIP to None causes kube-proxy **NOT TO CREATE** NAT rule in iptables mode, VIP in ipvs mode. There will be nothing for traffic load balancing across the pods selected by this particular Service selector

The second answer is "it could be". Why?

You are free to create headless Service with desired pods selector. DNS query to this Service will return the list of DNS A records for selected pods. Then you can use this data to implement load balancing **YOUR** way

Answer (score 1):

As much i know it's not possible to do the selector-based routing with ingress.

selector based routing is mostly used during a Blue-green deployment or canary deployment you can only achieve this by using the service mesh. You can use any of the service mesh like **istio** or **APP mesh** and you can do the selector base routing.

> I have deployed a statefulset in AKS - My goal is to load balance
> traffic to my statefulset.

if your goal is to just load balance traffic you can use the ingress controller maybe still not sure about scenrio you are trying to explain.

By default kubernetes **service** also **Load balance** the traffic across the **PODs**.

Flow will be something like `DNS > ingress > ingress controller > Kubernetes service (Load balancing here) > any of statefulset`

Comment: statefulset by nature require a headless service - so are you saying in the flow ingress controller can point to  a headless service which will load balance my traffic. Note - updated my scenario for clarity.

Comment: headless service is lacking in load balancing and proxying. if you have requirements you can create the clusterIP service with stateful sets. it's not always necessary to use the headless service with stateful sets.

Comment: if you want to do this `I want my ingress service to be able to load balance traffic across these statefulset pods` create new service with different name & same labels.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to [Harsh Manvar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5525824/harsh-manvar) answer but let me add also my 3 cents.

> My question is can any of the ingress controller support routing rules
> which can do Path based routing to endpoints based on selectors?
> Instead of routing to another service.

To the best of my knowledge, the answer to your question is **no, it can't** as it doesn't even depend on a particular ingress controller implementation. Note that various ingress controllers, no matter how different they may be when it comes to implementation, must conform to the general specification of the [ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), described in the official kubernetes documentation. You don't have different kinds of ingresses, depending on what controller is used.

[`Ingress`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) and [`Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) work on a different layer of abstraction. While `Service` exposes a set of pods using a selector e.g.:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
```

path-based routing performed by `Ingress` is always done between `Services`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test 
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: Thanks @mario I have updated the my question as a follow up to yours and Harsh's answer. Tl;dr can ingress loadbalance to a headless service?