# How do I use minikube's DNS?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, minikube

How do I use minikube's (cluster's) DNS? I want to receive all IP addresses associated with all pods for selected headless service? I don’t want to expose it outside the cluster. I am currently creating back-end layer.

As stated in the following answer: 
[What exactly is a headless service, what does it do/accomplish, and what are some legitimate use cases for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707840/what-exactly-is-a-headless-service-what-does-it-do-accomplish-and-what-are-som/52713482)

*„Instead of returning a single DNS A record, the DNS server will return multiple A records for the service, each pointing to the IP of an individual pod backing the service at that moment.”*

Thus the pods in back-end layer can communicate to each other.

I can’t use dig command. It is not installed in minikube. Eventually how do I install it? There is no apt available.

I hope this explains more accurately what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mentioned that you want to receive IP addresses associated with pods for selected service name for testing how does headless service work.

For only testing purposes you can use port-forwarding. You can forward traffic from your local machine to dns pod in your cluster. To do this, you need to run:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/kube-dns -n kube-system 5353:53
```

and it will expose kubs-dns service on your host. Then all you need is to use `dig` command (or alternative) to query the dns server.

```
dig @127.0.0.1 -p 5353 +tcp +short <service>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

You can also test your dns from inside of cluster e.g. by running a pod with interactive shell:

```
kubectl run --image tutum/dnsutils dns -it --rm -- bash
root@dns:/# dig +search <service>
```

Let me know it it helped.

Comment: Port forwarding is not required. Running dnsutils pod and using dig command inside it makes the job.

Answer (score -1):

As illustrated in [`kubernetes/minikube` issue 4397](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4397)

> Containers don't have an IP address by default.
>   You'll want to use `minikube service` or `minikube tunnel` to get endpoint information.

See "[hello-minikube/ Create a service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-a-service)":

> By default, the Pod is only accessible by its internal IP address within the Kubernetes cluster.
>
> To make the `hello-node` Container accessible from outside the Kubernetes virtual network, you have to expose the Pod as a Kubernetes Service.
>
> Expose the Pod to the public internet using the `kubectl expose` command:
>
> ```
> kubectl expose deployment hello-node --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
> ```
>
> The `--type=LoadBalancer` flag indicates that you want to expose your Service outside of the cluster.
>
> View the Service you just created:
>
> ```
> kubectl get services
>
> NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
> hello-node   LoadBalancer   10.108.144.78   <pending>     8080:30369/TCP   21s
> kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP
> ```
>
> On Minikube, the LoadBalancer type makes the Service accessible through the `minikube service` command.
>
> Run the following command:
>
> ```
> minikube service hello-node
> ```

Comment: @hal The Create service section I mention in the answer is about *pod* internal IP.