# kubernetes' readinessProbe prevents inter-pod communication during startup

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, readinessprobe, kubernetes-networking

From the Kubernetes documentation:

> A pod with containers reporting that they are not ready does not receive traffic through Kubernetes Services.

Does this mean that a failing `readinessProbe` supposed to prevent incoming traffic from pods within the same deployment? If I set up a `readinessProbe` that checks an endpoint which is only available after the pod joined the application cluster, then the endpoint never comes up. I checked manually with netcat, and the port of the not ready pod (which is used to establish cluster membership) is indeed not accessible from the other ready pods of the application cluster.

Is this expected? Any possible workaround for this?

Comment: what do you mean by "only available after the pod joined the application cluster"? do you mean ready?
for example, for kind `httpGet`, the kubelet sends an HTTP GET request to the service in the container itself
So which endpoint is not available?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

It is actually accessible, I probably did something wrong and came to the wrong conclusion. Ports that are bound directly to the pods' IP are accessible from the other pods even if the target pod is not ready.

Modifying the Service type to headless made the DNS entries return the pod IPs directly, rather than the service IPs. Setting `publishNotReadyAddresses: true` was necessary to be set to have the DNS entries before the ready state.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you are seeing is expected as it is used to determine if the pod is ready for traffic. In addition, the readiness behavior applies to all incoming traffic and is not limited to inter-pod comms within the same deployment. A suggestion as a workaround is to create separate services for readiness checks as this will not disrupt the traffic flow of your pods.

Comment: So there is no distinction between the "pod is ready to accept traffic", and the "pod can communicate internally with other pods"? This kinda sucks tbh. Not even sure why the second one is restricted at all.

I would like to prevent the rollout of the next pod until the previous pod successfully joined the application cluster. Which requires inter-pod networking to work.

Answer (score 0):

From your answer, you now have, by setting the Service to headless and enabling `publishNotReadyAddresses`:

```bash
+----------------------------------------------------+
| Kubernetes Cluster                                 |
|                                                    |
|   +----------------+   +----------------+          |
|   | Pod 1          |   | Pod 2          |          |
|   | (Ready)        |   | (Not Ready)    |          |
|   |                |   |                |          |
|   | +------------+ |   | +------------+ |          |
|   | | Container  | |   | | Container  | |          |
|   | |            | |   | |            | |          |
|   | +------------+ |   | +------------+ |          |
|   +----------------+   +----------------+          |
|                                                    |
|   Service: Headless                                |
|   publishNotReadyAddresses: true                   |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

With:

- **[Headless Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services)**: it does not have a Cluster IP. Instead, it allows direct access to the Pods' IPs. This is useful for cases where you don’t need load-balancing and a single Service IP.
  See also "[What is a headless service, what does it do/accomplish, and what are some legitimate use cases for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52707840/6309)"
- **[`publishNotReadyAddresses`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-hostname-and-subdomain-fields)**: When set to `true`, this setting allows the DNS system to return records for pods that are not ready. This is important in scenarios where you want other pods to be able to find and communicate with not-ready pods.

Your Kubernetes deployment would be:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: my-image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 10 # Adjust based on your app's needs
```

Service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-headless-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None # This makes the Service headless
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
```

The pods will be directly accessible through their IPs, even before they are ready. This configuration is particularly useful in scenarios like yours, where pods need to communicate with each other during their startup process, *before* they are marked as ready.